# How can I locate an Azure resource or setting creating empty WADMetrics Tables?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal, wadslogtable

We have a resource constantly creating completely empty WADMetrics tables on a storage account. We have a significant amount of Azure resources and are unable to locate what is creating them since they are completely empty. It appears 2 tables are created every 10 days designed to store data in 1Hour and 5Min buckets.

How can we determine what is creating these tables?

[image: WADMetrics]

Answer (score 2):

WAD stands for Windows Azure Diagnostics, which is probably enabled on a VM or other computing resource that uses this storage account for diagnostics.

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-diagnostics-template#wadmetrics-tables-in-storage) about WAD and specifically about WADMetrics table.

If you know what service is using this storage, you can simply [disable Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics).

Also, generally speaking, you can turn on storage diagnostics, specifically Table Service logs, to see who's creating those tables:

1. Go to [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/)
2. Choose the relevant storage account.
3. On the left pane - click **Diagnostics** and check 'Table logs'.
4. A new container named '$logs' will be created in the storage account, containing all the logs you've enabled.

Those logs audit all the operations executed on this storage Azure tables.

Comment: Unfortunately we have exactly 1 VM on the subscription and it does not have diagnostics enabled. I have enabled Table Logs in the meantime to hopefully catch the culprit but I may have to wait 10 days. Where do those logs get recorded?

Comment: @Vorotek you'll find the logs under 'logs' container in the blob storage

Comment: Thank you. It appeared as "$logs" for me but I could only see it from the Visual Studio Azure Server Explorer.