# Azure figure out what service is writing to WADLogsTable and turn it off

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

In Azure I have a table storage account and there is a table WADLogsTable.  It is being written too in surprisingly high volumes given the sites it is currently hosting.  This website is doing it's own logging and not using any Trace.* or anything like that.  I have to believe there is something automated populating the log tables.  I checked all the app services and each one has all the "Diagnostics logs" turned off.

How do I figure out what is populating the logs table and kill it?

UPDATE: Thanks @Gaurav Mantri So I know what resource it is coming from and it appears to be webjob related.  Not sure if it is required or optional.  Here is some sample redacted output:

- Executing: 'Function_Name' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'queue_name'.'
- SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - process
- Job host started
- SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
- Executed: 'Function_Name' (Succeeded)

Comment: Can you share  the content of one such record from this table?

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri I added some sample output.  I know that it is webjob related but not sure how to turn it off.  Or if it is required.

Comment: Do you use Azure Diagnostics application trace listener to trace your cloud service web or work role? As far as I know, the WADLogsTable(You could find it in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics-storage is used to store logs written in code using the application trace listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I locate an Azure resource or setting creating empty WADMetrics Tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147256/how-can-i-locate-an-azure-resource-or-setting-creating-empty-wadmetrics-tables)